# Transforming an array of lists

Tags: python, list

Consider an array of two lists:

```
In [98]: toks
Out[98]:
[['1.423',
  '0.046',
  '98.521',
  '0.010',
  '0.000',
  '0.000',
  '5814251520.0',
  '769945600.0',
  '18775908352.0',
  '2.45024350208e+11',
  '8131.903',
  '168485.073',
  '0.0',
  '0.0',
  '0.022',
  '372.162',
  '1123.041',
  '1448.424'],
 ['71.765',
  '0.478',
  '27.757',
  '0.0',
  '0.0',
  '0.0',
  '5839618048.0',
  '769945600.0',
  '18776162304.0',
  '2.44998729728e+11',
  '0.0',
  '0.0',
  '1640.0',
  '1608.0',
  '0.0',
  '3775.0',
  '12858.0',
  '6723.0']]
```

So we would like to convert the list to a Point

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'usr sys idl wai hiq siq  used  buff  cach  free 
     read  writ recv  send majpf minpf alloc  vmfree')
```

Doing the conversion directly **does** work:

```
  In [99]: Point(*toks[0])
Out[99]: Point(usr='1.423', sys='0.046', idl='98.521', wai='0.010', hiq='0.000', siq='0.000', used='5814251520.0',
 buff='769945600.0', cach='18775908352.0', free='2.45024350208e+11', read='8131.903', writ='168485.073', recv='0.0',
  send='0.0', majpf='0.022', minpf='372.162', alloc='1123.041', vmfree='1448.424')
```

But attempting to create the Point via an iteration does not:

```
pts = [map(lambda x: Point(*x), tokarr) for tokarr in toks]


In [90]: pts = [map(lambda x: Point(*x), tokarr) for tokarr in toks0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-a30764943aa1> in <module>()
----> 1 pts = [map(lambda x: Point(*x), tokarr) for tokarr in toks0]

<ipython-input-90-a30764943aa1> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 pts = [map(lambda x: Point(*x), tokarr) for tokarr in toks0]

TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 19 arguments (2 given)
```

I need the latter construction because the intention is to iterate over a collection  of lists and convert each entry to a Point. How to do this?

Comment: You should either use map or list comprehension.

Comment: @Alik  Please be explicit: i.e. show some code.  If you notice the OP includes an attempted  list comprehension.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve with ``map``. Isn't ``[Point(*tokarr) for tokarr in toks]`` enough?

Comment: @fjarri  That may well be so: you are suggesting an implicit map. I will try it.

Comment: @fjarri  Pls make that an answer and I wil award. btw why does my (apparently overkill/redundant) invocation of map(.) not even work at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you tried to use `map` isn't quite right. You want the `lambda` to be applied to each element of the root list, not to each element of each child list, right?

Is this what you were looking for?

```
pts = map(lambda x: Point(*x), toks)
```

Comment: actually this answer most directly addresses my misuse of the lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
pts = [Point(*tokarr) for tokarr in toks]
```

will work.

If you want to do it with `map`:

```
pts = list(map(lambda x: Point(*x), toks))
```

Comment: yes that does work: and will award in the ten mins or so required to wait.  In the meantime: why does my (apparently redundant ) map construction not work at all?

Comment: Each `tokarr` you have is a 1D list. Then you map a `Point` over it; this results in calling `Point` with 1 argument for each element of `tokarr` (the error tells about 2 arguments because it counts ``self``), when it requires 18.

Comment: Got it. Actually the other answer leekaiinthesky was the first one to address my misuse of the 2d array directly. Both of your answers are good but I can only award one.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Then I will upvote this one too to compensate. Both are clearly helpful.

Comment: There is no need to use `list`. `map` already returns a list. cc @javadba

Comment: @Alik: not anymore in Py3.

Comment: @fjarri oh, I forgot, that it now returns iterator.